# HTML form submit to PHP

Tags: php, html, forms

Okay so I have a file called proxy.php with these contents and what I want to do with it is that, if any of the forms are filled with a value and submitted, the "if" check should become true and run the commands but I have a problem and even though I submit a value, it doesn't go into the "if" check. If I put the commands out of "if" check, they start to work but not inside them.

```
<html>
<body>

<br>
<form action="proxy.php" method="post">


<br>

Host Port 1: <input type="text" name="hport" />
Server Port 1: <input type="text" name="sport"/>
<br>
Host Port 2: <input type="text" name="hport2"/>
Server Port 2: <input type="text" name="sport2"/>

<br>


<input type="submit" />
</form>

</body>
</html> 

<?php
include('Net/SSH2.php');



$_POST["ip"]="iphere";
$_POST["pass"]="passhere";



$ssh = new Net_SSH2($_POST["ip"]);
if (!$ssh->login('root', $_POST["pass"])) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}


if($_POST['hport1']){

echo $ssh->exec('ls');
echo $ssh->exec('screen -S Proxy1 -X quit');
echo $ssh->exec('Run these commands');
}

if($_POST['hport2']){

echo $ssh->exec('ls');
echo $ssh->exec('screen -S Proxy2 -X quit');
echo $ssh->exec('Run these commands');
}


echo $ssh->exec('exit');


?>
```

Comment: It might not be the whole issue, but your form's input is `hport`; your code is looking for `hport1`.

Comment: and what is the value of $_POST['hport'] when you submit the form?

Comment: I haven't done PHP in a while, but isn't there an isset function you can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value $_POST['hport1'] is null because you are posting 'hport' from html.
Try with that change.

```
if($_POST['hport']){
        echo $ssh->exec('ls');
        echo $ssh->exec('screen -S Proxy1 -X quit');
        echo $ssh->exec('Run these commands');
}
```

If the problem still persists, use isset($_POST['hport']) to check whether the value for the variable 'hport' is set or not.
   You can check the POST values mannually, use

```
<?php var_dump($_POST); ?>
```

OR

```
<?php
    echo '<pre>' . print_r($_POST) . '</pre>';
?>
```

for displaying the $_POST array values in a readable format. Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you. Yes that was the issue. It was just a typo and worked after I fixed it up. We didn't need the isset function

Answer (score 1):

could try and use isset to check the details.

```
if(isset($_POST['Name of field to check for'])){
 ////CODE HERE
 }
```

An alternative might be to check if the form was submitted and then do something

```
if(empty($_POST) === false){
///CODE HERE
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **isset()** & **empty()** inbuilt function of PHP to check the variables..

```
if(isset($_POST['hport'] && !empty($_POST['hport'])){
echo $ssh->exec('ls');
echo $ssh->exec('screen -S Proxy1 -X quit');
echo $ssh->exec('Run these commands');
}

if(isset($_POST['hport2'] && !empty($_POST['hport2'])){
echo $ssh->exec('ls');
echo $ssh->exec('screen -S Proxy2 -X quit');
echo $ssh->exec('Run these commands');
}
```